# PostgreSQL function with union not returning all records

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to create a complex function, i've only gotten to like step 3 of what i need it to do. This stuff is a little advance for me. So, i've tried the follow SQL and i get 2 records back- which is what I expect. However, when i try the same SQL within a function (and input variable) i only get 1 record back. If i remove the first select and union statement, i get the other record.
The only parameter i'm passing in us userUuid.

Running on a docker container - postgres:11.5-alpine

**PLAIN WORKING SQL:** (getting back 2 records as expected)

```
SELECT
        assets.name AS assetName,
        assets.uuid AS assetUuid,
        assets.workflow_uuid,
        projects.name,
        projects.uuid,
        projects.project_category_uuid,
        'Project Role' AS classType
    FROM
        projects
        JOIN assets ON assets.project_uuid = projects.uuid
    WHERE projects.project_category_uuid IN (
        SELECT projectCategoryUuid FROM "UserProjectCategoryRoles" 
        WHERE "UserProjectCategoryRoles".user_uuid = '65a749ee-5417-4187-a1b1-bcfa9a401267'
        
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        assets.name AS assetName,
        assets.uuid AS assetUuid,
        assets.workflow_uuid,
        projects.name,
        projects.uuid,
        projects.project_category_uuid,
        'Workflow Role' AS classType
    FROM
        assets
        JOIN projects ON projects.uuid = assets.project_uuid
    
    WHERE assets.workflow_uuid IN (
        SELECT workflowUuid FROM "UserWorkflowRoles" 
        WHERE "UserWorkflowRoles".user_uuid = '65a749ee-5417-4187-a1b1-bcfa9a401267'
        
    );
```

**Not working function** (only getting back either or record)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "public"."revisionsForReview"(
    IN userUuid VARCHAR, 
    INOUT name VARCHAR, 
    INOUT uuid VARCHAR, 
    INOUT project_category_uuid VARCHAR,
    INOUT assetName VARCHAR,
    INOUT assetUuid VARCHAR,
    INOUT workflow_uuid VARCHAR,
    INOUT classType VARCHAR
)
 AS $BODY$BEGIN
        SELECT
            projects.name,
            projects.uuid,
            projects.project_category_uuid,
            assets.name AS assetName,
            assets.uuid AS assetUuid,
            assets.workflow_uuid,
            'Project Role' AS classType
        FROM
            projects
            JOIN assets ON assets.project_uuid = projects.uuid
        WHERE projects.project_category_uuid IN (
            SELECT projectCategoryUuid FROM "UserProjectCategoryRoles" 
            WHERE "UserProjectCategoryRoles".user_uuid = userUuid 
        )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            projects.name,
            projects.uuid,
            projects.project_category_uuid,
            assets.name AS assetName,
            assets.uuid AS assetUuid,
            assets.workflow_uuid,
            'Workflow Role' AS classType
        FROM
            assets
            JOIN projects ON projects.uuid = assets.project_uuid
        WHERE assets.workflow_uuid IN (
            SELECT workflowUuid FROM "UserWorkflowRoles" 
            WHERE "UserWorkflowRoles".user_uuid = userUuid
        )
        INTO name, uuid, project_category_uuid, assetName, assetUuid, workflow_uuid, classType;

END$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Appreciate the help, again, this is the start of my function. I'll need to figure out how to loop through and do other things to the data before i return it. I just want to understand things up to this point. I normally am ok with doing everything in PHP Laravel and using its migrations. But these joins and processing are going to take a lot longer processing in app, and running multiple db calls.
Also the unions are querying views, which i may get rid of later, and keep everything in the function.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, your "function" isn't a function but a procedure. Try an actual function returning a table.

Comment: whoops. thanks for pointing that out. i switched over to a function and returned a table

Comment: Not directly related but Postgres supports uuid as a native data type. Define them as such. For example instead of "*assets.uuid  varchar*" define it as "*assets.uuid uuid*". BTW because it is a valid data type you should avoid having *uuid* as a column name.

Comment: @Belayer oh cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to "sticky bit" for pointing out using a function instead of a stored proc. Got it working (after adjusting some type casting- which i found really strange since it was varying vs text, thought those were the same from an app consumption point of view, but i guess not exactly the same).

i'll just post what ended up working- just in case someone else runs into a similar issue

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revisions_for_review (
    input_user_uuid VARCHAR
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    asset_name TEXT,
    asset_uuid VARCHAR,
    name VARCHAR, 
    uuid VARCHAR, 
    project_category_uuid VARCHAR,
    workflow_uuid VARCHAR,
    class_type TEXT
        )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE

 BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT
            assets.name::TEXT AS asset_name,
            assets.uuid AS asset_uuid,
            assets.workflow_uuid,
            projects.name,
            projects.uuid,
            projects.project_category_uuid,
            'Project Role' AS class_type
        FROM
            projects
            JOIN assets ON assets.project_uuid = projects.uuid
        WHERE projects.project_category_uuid IN (
            SELECT projectCategoryUuid FROM "UserProjectCategoryRoles" 
            WHERE "UserProjectCategoryRoles".user_uuid = input_user_uuid 
        )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            assets.name::TEXT AS asset_name,
            assets.uuid AS asset_uuid,
            assets.workflow_uuid,
            projects.name,
            projects.uuid,
            projects.project_category_uuid,
            'Workflow Role' AS class_type
        FROM
            assets
            JOIN projects ON projects.uuid = assets.project_uuid
        WHERE assets.workflow_uuid IN (
            SELECT workflowUuid FROM "UserWorkflowRoles" 
            WHERE "UserWorkflowRoles".user_uuid = input_user_uuid
        );
        

END;$$
```

Comment: You don't even need PL/pgSQL for this. A simple `language sql` function will be just as good

Comment: oh, i'll look into that too. as mentioned in the first post, this is just step 3 of creating the function. There's still a few more steps i need to accomplish. Just want to make sure my very basic understanding of functions is correct, so i can keep validating the output as i add more. thank you